# Remote Desktop Connection not working on Raspberry Pi 3B+

Tags: raspbian, raspberry-pi-desktop

I had tried:

*$ sudo apt-get install tightvncserver*

and

*$ sudo apt-get install xrdp*

and it worked however, after turning off the Pi and coming back it no longer worked.

I then tried:

*$ sudo apt-get remove xrdp vnc4server tightvncserver*

*$ sudo apt-get install tightvncserver*

*$ sudo apt-get install xrdp*

It still doesn't work, I keep getting this error message:

[image]

Comment: perhaps you need to `systemctl start xrdp` and `systemctl enable xrdp` ?

Comment: systemctl start xrdp and systemctl enable xrdp didn't work

Comment: "didn't work" ... so, no errors or other messages that could be meaningful?